# How to remove screenshots from Google Play app or game listing page

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I have published a game on Google Play store and set all the required information.

Later I wanted to remove the screenshots from its listing page and upload new screenshots.

I went on to Google Play Console, removed the old pictures and added the new ones but when I access the game listing page the old photos are still there.

So, how to remove old pictures from the game page?

Comment: they will remove with in 20 minutes automatically if you updated latest and removed old ones

Comment: Abhinav Gupta, but i have already removed the old ones(from console). And now it show booth of them. The old ones and the new ones. You know another solutions?

Comment: That sounds like a bug, if you really did remove the old ones from your console. I'd try again. If it still doesn't work after the publish goes live, contact Google Play developer support using the help menu in the Play Console.

Comment: Thank you Nick  . This is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Someone previously uploaded screenshots on a different language setting, which made it difficult to find by the current team.

**For example:**

- If you upload images on the language `English (United States) - en-US`, it won't be displayed on the same store with the settings `English (United Kingdom) - en-GB`. To delete screenshots, you would have to go through all languages and delete them there.

**Navigate to:**

- Google Play Store Console > Store Presence > Store listing > Product details > Change the language > Delete Screenshot(s):

[image]